# Python: remove Greek diacritics/accents

Tags: python, string, unicode, string-formatting

Is there a relatively straightforward way of removing diacritics from Greek strings? For example, if the string is "Ο πάνω όροφος" I want it to become "ο πανω οροφος", still in Greek, without the accents. I want to avoid string replace as it can be slow and most answers to similar questions use unidecode which converts the greek characters to english and I don't want that.

Comment: Why do that? They don't affect sorting or searching if you use the correct collation - or rather, if you don't use the *wrong* collation. You'd only have a problem if you used binary sorting/comparisons

Comment: Whatever the boss wants really. Most official papers for anything need to have capitals only and without diacritics.

Comment: In that case you need to convert the letters to uppercase, not remove diacritics. You need to specify the proper capitalisation, not manually remove diacritics

Comment: BTW there's no what the boss wants, especially in this. Greek developers struggled with multiple codepages 20 years ago and were relieved when things moved to Unicode in 2000 - add a couple of years until everyone saved their web pages in UTF8. Any problem you may encountered was already solved decades ago without mangling and replacements

Comment: Would you like to add an answer showing the proper way for doing this in Python?

Comment: Try [normalizing the string](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) with `unicodedata.normalize` before using `upper`

Comment: Nope, not working, not with any of the four forms. Can you make it work on your machine using Python3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Most official papers for anything need to have capitals only and without diacritics.

Does this work?

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> s="Ο πάνω όροφος"
>>> d = {ord('\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}'):None}
>>> ud.normalize('NFD',s).upper().translate(d)
'Ο ΠΑΝΩ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ'
```

Normalizing with NFD separates base code points from diacritics.  The `d` translation table lists Unicode ordinal translations...in this case, deleting the diacritic.  I'm not familiar with Greek diacritic usage so the table may need to be expanded.

`.replace('\u0301','')` could be used for one accent, but `.translate()` is more efficient if there are multiple replacements.

Skip `.upper()` to match your original question:

```
>>> ud.normalize('NFD',s).translate(d)
'Ο πανω οροφος'
```